# Lagrange multipliers with implicit constraint function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

I was trying to find maxima/minima for $z= x^3 + y^3$ , subject to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.
I tried to find it by using $f(x,y,z) = x^3 + y^3$ 
and $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ 
& by using the constraint as $g(x,y,z) = 1$.
However that didn't workout , the way as expected.
What am I missing here? How should $f$ & $g$ be set up to calculate Lagrange multipliers correctly?

Comment: You should show your calculations.

Comment: The problem does not make too much sense. Do you need the minima for $z$? The you have two constraints. One is $z=x^3+y^3$. The other is $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: basically solved for x, y, z, d , the below system 
[-2*d*x + 3*x**2 = 0, -2*d*y + 3*y**2 = 0, -2*d*z = 0 , x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1 = 0]

Comment: Please show your calculations. Use Mathjax to format equations

Comment: I am trying to find either maxima/minima

Comment: @Kedar_dg can you please clarify the first line of your question? $z=x^3+y^3$ is an equation and not function. What do you mean by maximize/minimize the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}f(x,y,z)&=z\\g(x,y,z)&=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0\\h(x,y,z)&=x^3+y^3-z=0\end{align}$$
Then take the derivatives of $f+\lambda g+\mu h$:
$$0+2\lambda x+3\mu x^2=0\\0+2\lambda y+3\mu y^2=0\\1+2\lambda z-\mu =0$$
We can rewrite these as $$x(2\lambda+3\mu x)=0\\y(2\lambda+3\mu y)=0
\\z=\frac{\mu-1}{2\lambda}$$
Obviously $x$ and $y$ cannot be simultaneously $0$, since it would imply $z=0$ in $h=0$, but $(0,0,0)$ does not verify $g=0$. Then you have three cases you need to solve (1) $x=0$, (2) $y=0$, and (3) $x=y\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks Andrei , I believe that answers my question!

Comment: I am glad. Please let me know if you need more help, and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.